# Is there a way to not make my list disappear?

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to make some code, this part doesn't work. Because it keeps saying my list index is out of range and it looks like items from my list are disappearing. If i take a look at the code I can't find why it's not working. Anyone any idea why this is not working?

```
ts = [[4, 5], [9, 6], [2, 10]]
repeats = 3
for i in range(repeats):
    cts = ts
    t = ts[i]
    cts.remove(t)
    print(ts, t)

###    [[6, 9], [2, 10]] [4, 5]
###    [[6, 9]] [2, 10]
###
###    Exception has occurred: IndexError
###    list index out of range
###
###      File "MyFile.py", line 12, in <module>
###        t = ts[i]
```

Comment: If the repeats is the number of list elements simply replace that with len(ts).

Comment: `cts` is acting as a reference to `ts`. So `cts.remove(t)` is modifying the original list. You need a copy (probably just a shallow). `cts = ts.copy()`

Comment: Why do you have `cts = ts` and `cts.remove()`? `cts.remove()` doesn't do anything since you are constantly copying the original list.

Comment: @BokiX that doesn't _copy_ the original list, it only creates a variable that references the original list

Comment: Does my code below the post work?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Yes, and that is why it is disappearing..

Comment: @BokiX your comment above says _"you are constantly copying the original list"_, which OP's code doesn't do.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: What are you trying to do here?. The program stops execution even before the list gets completely empty. cts.remove(t) is removing each element when the loop runs. But when you are trying to take the 2nd indexed element ie, t = ts[2] from the list, it only contains one element [9, 6]. That's is why your program shows index out of the range. If you don't want the list to completely disappear add a break case according to your requirement.

Comment: This is for a sort of competition, this is also just a part of my code.

Comment: Well, then I'd suggest it's the wrong part of your code. You're clearly attempting to do something, but are going about it in a strange way - we can tell you a different, also strange way to do it... but it probably isn't the best or even correct solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why this is happening is because you have `cts = ts` in every loop iteration. So you are modifying the original `ts` list.
This code should do what you need:

```
ts = [[4, 5], [9, 6], [2, 10]]
for i in range(len(ts)):
    cts = ts.copy()
    t = ts[i]
    cts.remove(t)
    print(ts, t)
```

Comment: Why is this any better than simply `for i in range(len(ts)): \n print(ts, ts[i])`? You are copying a list every iteration, removing an element, and then discarding that work.

Comment: He is probably using a simple code to present what he wants to us. So I left it there in case he is doing more than he is showing us.

Answer (score 0):

For removing values from `ts`, you can simple do this.

```
ts = [[4, 5], [9, 6], [2, 10]]
for _ in range(len(ts)):
    del ts[-1] # You can use `0` as well
```

OR

```
ts = [[4, 5], [9, 6], [2, 10]]
del ts
```